# Angularjs and codeigniter routing not working

Tags: angularjs, codeigniter

Below is my CODEIGNITER 'testing_route' view page code

```
 <div ng-app="tutorialWebApp">
 <a href="#/home">Home</a><br />
 <a href="#/about">About</a><br />

<div ng-view></div>
  </div>


  //angularjs

  <script>
        var app = angular.module('tutorialWebApp',['ngRoute']);
              app.config(function ($routeProvider,$locationProvider) {
   $routeProvider

.when("/home", {templateUrl: "<?php echo site_url('Main/demo1');?>"})

.when("/about", {templateUrl: "<?php echo site_url('Main/demo2');?>"})

// else 404
.otherwise({redirectTo: '/testview'});
 $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);

});
</script>
```

and my 'main' CONTROLLER code is as follows

```
  function testing_route()
 {
  $this->load->view('admin/testing_route');
 }

function demo1()
{
 $this->load->view('admin/demo1');
}
function demo2()
{
$this->load->view('admin/demo2');
}
```

whenever i click on home/about the page is not working and not getting any errors also,i tried all the solutions using $locationProvider also but nothing done helpfull,please help me how to load pages or how to do spa application on page loading using CODEIGNITER and ANGULARJS

Comment: put your views in admin subfolder.

Comment: its in the admin folder only

Answer (score 0):

Change your routes, as you define in routes.php

```
.when("/home", {templateUrl : "Main/demo1"})

.when("/about", {templateUrl : "Main/demo2"})
```

This will work.